# Unable to execute jar file due to main manifest attribute missing

Tags: java, jar

I have below project structure:

```
->bin
->lib
->resources
->src
 ->DemoFramework
  ->FirstDemo.java
```

In lib folder, I have an external jar that I need in my application. Its name is `ext.jar`. In resources, I have `Manifest.txt` file, whose content is given below.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . lib/ext.jar
Main-Class: DemoFramework.FirstDemo
```

I am using below command to generate jar:

```
javac -cp ".;./lib/ext.jar" src/DemoFramework/*.java -d bin
```

Basically I am putting all class files into bin folder so that in final jar file, source code is not visible.
Then I am issuing below command:

```
jar cmf resources/Manifest.txt project.jar bin lib
```

The jar file is successfully created but when I run it, it says:
`no main manifest attribute, in project.jar`

I am confused about this error, no idea why it is happening.
Can you guys help me to sort it out?
Thanks.

Comment: When creating manifest file by hand, it must have **empty line at the end**. Alternatively, use `e` and the class-name to have `jar` build the manifest for you correctly. But after fixing that you will have 'unable to load' because putting the superdirectory `bin` in the jar is wrong.